# How can I import data from MySQL(AWS RDS) using Logstash of Elastic Cloud via AWS VPC?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-rds, aws-vpc, elastic-cloud

I'm trying to import some data from AWS RDS to `Elasticsearch of Hosted Elastic Cloud`
- It's not `AWS Elasticsearch Service`

What I want to do is below.

- What: Data import
- From: AWS RDS MySQL
- To: Elasticsearch in Elastic Cloud
- How: Using Logstash of Elastic Cloud

However, my AWS RDS MySQL is in AWS VPC and Elastic Cloud doesn't provide static ip address (please see [Elasticsearch F&Q](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-faq.html))

So Logstash can't access to AWS RDS MySQL preserving security rule of AWS VPC.

In previous data transfer case, I used to add trasferer's ip address to whitelist of VPC. For this case, it can't be done.

I totally don't know whether this trial is wrong or not.

How can I handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I concluded that there is no way to do that for now. However, there is compromise plan. By setting `Logstash` EC2 instance in Amazon VPC, `Logstash` can access to AWS RDS MySQL. With Elastic cloud's credential, it can also send data to `Elasticsearch` in Elastic Cloud.